# disabling form submit in html and css only

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am adding a code block to a page where all js is disabled and stripped out. I want to add a recaptcha to a form to cut down on spam. I've nearly got it, but can't get it to work.

My questions are:

1. The js code I am using to validate the required fields gets stripped. Is there any way to put the validation back in without using js?
2. I can't figure out how to connect the enable submit to the recapthca checkbox.

Here's the code as far as I've got it to work...

```html
<!-- Note :
   - You can modify the font style and form style to suit your website. 
   - Code lines with comments Do not remove this code are required for the form to work properly, make sure that you do not remove these lines of code. 
   - The Mandatory check script can modified as to suit your business needs. 
   - It is important that you test the modified form before going live.-->
<div id='crmWebToEntityForm' class='zcwf_lblLeft crmWebToEntityForm' style='background-color: white;color: black;max-width: 600px;'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
   <META HTTP-EQUIV ='content-type' CONTENT='text/html;charset=UTF-8'>
   <form action='https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm' name=WebToLeads2983403000000507130 method='POST' onSubmit='javascript:document.charset="UTF-8"; return checkMandatory2983403000000507130()' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
 <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='xnQsjsdp' value='d8a8809b8fe787eb5f1520e8345aa1f4461cf539b2b1505c31cd3765336f8089'></input> 
 <input type='hidden' name='zc_gad' id='zc_gad' value=''></input> 
 <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='xmIwtLD' value='da656ccd402f059702a554831941786995278d8da723e570a30ed6c9d5d4a5b5'></input> 
 <input type='text'  style='display:none;' name='actionType' value='TGVhZHM='></input>
 <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='returnURL' value='https://www.monkeytronics.co.nz/' > </input>
     <!-- Do not remove this code. -->
<style>

/* <!-- Stick in a recaptcha --> */

body {
    margin:0;
    background-image:url(https://cdn.theculturetrip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/gettyimages-904801296.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.captcha {
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    border:2px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-radius:10px;
    color:#4c4a4b;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .captcha {
        flex-direction:column;
    }
    .text {
        margin:.5em!important;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .logo {
        align-self: center!important;
    }
    .spinner {
        margin:2em .5em .5em .5em!important;
    }
}

.text {
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:500;
    margin-right:1em;
}
.spinner {
    position:relative;
    width:2em;
    height:2em;
    display:flex;
    margin:2em 1em;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
input[type="checkbox"] { position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
input[type="checkbox"]+.checkmark {
    display:inline-block;
    width:2em;
    height:2em;
    background-color:#fcfcfc;
    border:2.5px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-radius:3px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"]+.checkmark span {
    content:'';
    position:relative;/*
    position:absolute;
    border-bottom:3px solid;
    border-right:3px solid;
    border-color:#029f56;*/
    margin-top:-3px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    width:.75em;
    height:1.2em;
    opacity:0;
}
input[type="checkbox"]+.checkmark>span:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    height:3px;
    bottom:0;left:0;
    background-color:#029f56;
}
input[type="checkbox"]+.checkmark>span:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:3px;
    bottom:0;right:0;
    background-color:#029f56;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkmark { 
    animation:2s spin forwards;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkmark>span { 
    animation:1s fadein 1.9s forwards;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkmark>span:after {animation:.3s bottomslide 2s forwards;}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkmark>span:before {animation:.5s rightslide 2.2s forwards;}
@keyframes fadein {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}
@keyframes bottomslide {
    0% {width:0;}
    100% {width:100%;}
}
@keyframes rightslide {
    0% {height:0;}
    100% {height:100%;}
}
.logo {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
    height:100%;
    align-self:flex-end;
    margin:0.5em 1em;
}
.logo img {
    height:2em;
    width:2em;
}
.logo p {
    color:#9d9ba7;
    margin:0;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:700;
    margin:.4em 0 .2em 0;
}
.logo small {
    color:#9d9ba7;
    margin:0;
    font-size:.8em;
}
@keyframes spin {
    10% {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border-width:6px;
    }
    30% {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border-radius:50%;
        border-width:1em;
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        border-color:rgb(199,218,245);
    }
    50% {
        width:2em;
        height:2em;
        border-radius:50%;
        border-width:4px;
        border-color:rgb(199,218,245);
        border-right-color:rgb(89,152,239);
    }
    70% {
        border-width:4px;
        border-color:rgb(199,218,245);
        border-right-color:rgb(89,152,239);
    }
    90% {
        border-width:4px;
    }
    100% {
        width:2em;
        height:2em;
        border-radius:50%;
        transform: rotate(720deg);
        border-color:transparent;
    }
}
::selection {
    background-color:transparent;
    color:teal;
}
::-moz-selection {
    background-color:transparent;
    color:teal;
}


html,body{
    margin: 0px;
}
#crmWebToEntityForm.zcwf_lblLeft {
    width:100%;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#crmWebToEntityForm.zcwf_lblLeft * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#crmWebToEntityForm{text-align: left;}
#crmWebToEntityForm * {
    direction: ltr;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_title {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 0px 6px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_col_fld input[type=text], .zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_col_fld textarea {
    width: 60%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    resize: vertical;
    border-radius: 2px;
    float: left;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_col_lab {
    width: 30%;
    word-break: break-word;
    padding: 0px 6px 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_col_fld {
    float: left;
    width: 68%;
    padding: 0px 6px 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_privacy{padding: 6px;}
.zcwf_lblLeft .wfrm_fld_dpNn{display: none;}
.dIB{display: inline-block;}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_col_fld_slt {
    width: 60%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    resize: vertical;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_row:after, .zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_col_fld:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_col_help {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    font-size: 16px;
    max-width: 35%;
    word-break: break-word;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_help_icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_row {margin: 15px 0px;}
.zcwf_lblLeft .formsubmit {
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_privacy_txt {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #333;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_button_submit {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #00C3E8;
    border: 2px solid #00C3E8;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_button {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px 23px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_tooltip_over{
    position: relative;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_tooltip_ctn{
    position: absolute;
    background: #dedede;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    top: 3px;
    border-radius: 4px;word-break: break-all;
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 150px;
    color: #333;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_ckbox{
    float: left;
}
.zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_file{
    width: 55%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}
.clearB:after{
    content:'';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    .zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_col_lab, .zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_col_fld {
        width: auto;
        float: none !important;
    }
    .zcwf_lblLeft .zcwf_col_help {width: 40%;}
}
</style>
<div class='zcwf_title' style='font-size:20px; max-width: 600px;color: #00C3E8;'>Contact Monkeytronics</div>
<div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:16px; font-family: Arial;'><label for='First_Name'>First Name</label></div><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='First_Name' name='First Name' maxlength='40'></input><div class='zcwf_col_help'></div></div></div>
<div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:16px; font-family: Arial;'><label for='Last_Name'>Last Name<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Last_Name' name='Last Name' maxlength='80'></input><div class='zcwf_col_help'></div></div></div>
<div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:16px; font-family: Arial;'><label for='Email'>Email<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' ftype='email' id='Email' name='Email' maxlength='100'></input><div class='zcwf_col_help'></div></div></div>
<div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:16px; font-family: Arial;'><label for='Company'>Company<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='text' id='Company' name='Company' maxlength='100'></input><div class='zcwf_col_help'></div></div></div>
<div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_lab' style='font-size:16px; font-family: Arial;'><label for='Description'>How can we help?<span style='color:red;'>*</span></label></div><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><textarea id='Description' name='Description'></textarea><div class='zcwf_col_help'></div></div></div><div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_lab'></div><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='submit' id='formsubmit' class='formsubmit zcwf_button_submit' value='Submit' title='Submit'><input type='reset' class='zcwf_button' name='reset' value='Reset' title='Reset'></div></div>

<div class="captcha">
    <div class="spinner">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="$(this).attr('disabled','disabled');">
            <span class="checkmark"><span>&nbsp;</span></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        I'm not a robot
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://forum.nox.tv/core/index.php?media/9-recaptcha-png/"/>
        <p>reCAPTCHA</p>
        <small>Privacy - Terms</small>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function validateEmail2983403000000507130()
    {
        var form = document.forms['WebToLeads2983403000000507130'];
        var emailFld = form.querySelectorAll('[ftype=email]');
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < emailFld.length; i++)
        {
            var emailVal = emailFld[i].value;
            if((emailVal.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')).length!=0 )
            {
                var atpos=emailVal.indexOf('@');
                var dotpos=emailVal.lastIndexOf('.');
                if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=emailVal.length)
                {
                    alert('Please enter a valid email address. ');
                    emailFld[i].focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

      function checkMandatory2983403000000507130() {
        var mndFileds = new Array('Company','Last Name','Email','Description');
        var fldLangVal = new Array('Company','Last Name','Email','How can we help?');
        for(i=0;i<mndFileds.length;i++) {
          var fieldObj=document.forms['WebToLeads2983403000000507130'][mndFileds[i]];
          if(fieldObj) {
            if (((fieldObj.value).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')).length==0) {
             if(fieldObj.type =='file')
                { 
                 alert('Please select a file to upload.'); 
                 fieldObj.focus(); 
                 return false;
                } 
            alert(fldLangVal[i] +' cannot be empty'); 
              fieldObj.focus();
              return false;
            }  else if(fieldObj.nodeName=='SELECT') {
             if(fieldObj.options[fieldObj.selectedIndex].value=='-None-') {
                alert(fldLangVal[i] +' cannot be none'); 
                fieldObj.focus();
                return false;
               }
            } else if(fieldObj.type =='checkbox'){
             if(fieldObj.checked == false){
                alert('Please accept  '+fldLangVal[i]);
                fieldObj.focus();
                return false;
               } 
             } 
             try {
                 if(fieldObj.name == 'Last Name') {
                name = fieldObj.value;
                }
            } catch (e) {}
            }
        }
        if(!validateEmail2983403000000507130()){return false;}
        document.querySelector('.crmWebToEntityForm .formsubmit').setAttribute('disabled', true);
    }

function tooltipShow2983403000000507130(el){
    var tooltip = el.nextElementSibling;
    var tooltipDisplay = tooltip.style.display;
    if(tooltipDisplay == 'none'){
        var allTooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('zcwf_tooltip_over');
        for(i=0; i<allTooltip.length; i++){
            allTooltip[i].style.display='none';
        }
        tooltip.style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        tooltip.style.display='none';
    }
}
</script>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Javascript is required to achieve your goals. At a minimum, ReCaptCHA requires JS to operate: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#automatically_bind_the_challenge_to_a_button

Comment: Disabling the form submit without javascript is easy. Re-enabling without javascript will be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using required on input elements in the form,
for the captcha you should add some functionality when you click on submit you should check if the captcha checkbox was clicked (right now theres some jquery code on it but you dont have jquery on your web)

Answer (score 0):

Use the  **disabled** attribute!

Here is an example:

```
<form> <input type = "submit" disabled="disabled">Submit</input></form>
```

Using this will grey-out the button!